# Responsive Dialog in Durandal 2.1?

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I found the following:

[Responsive Durandal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792129/responsive-durandal-dialog)

However I don't see any documentation on making the dialog responsive in 2.1.  I have a dialog that extends in height as the user selects stuff - eventually the dialog gets taller than the viewport and there's no scroll or anything so it's a total mess on mobile devices.  I've tried using the "reposition" functionality from the docs but this doesn't seem to do much.  Any advice around this would be much appreciated.

```
        dialog.show('viewmodels/doThis', { data: data });
        addEditDialog.context.reposition('doThis'); // doesn't help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read to set [max-height CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) and [overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) **auto**

```
 .dialog { overflow: visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit }
```

it looks like this:

```
 .dialog{
        max-height:480px; /* height of the device for example*/
        overflow-y:auto;  /* if the content is nore than max-height the scrollbar will show up*/
 }
```

or just use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  /*code for destop*/
  .dialog{

   }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
/*code for ipad and netbooks*/
  .dialog{

   }
 }
@media (max-width: 480px) {
/*code for mobile here*/
   .dialog{

   }
}
```