# How to make durandal dialog draggable and resizable?

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-draggable, durandal, jquery-ui-resizable

I was wondering whether it is possible to make the dialog/popup in durandal resizable and draggable using jQuery.
in the attached hook, 
I added this:

```
$('.modalHost').resizable().draggable();
```

or

`$('.modalHost').resizable();
    $('.modalHost').draggable();`

And what got rendered is very weird.

This works: 
`$('.modalHost').draggable();`
but as soon as I add resizable it breaks it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've already looked at this but I was hoping for a more future proof solution:
[Responsive Durandal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792129/responsive-durandal-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the resize CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

```
.modalHost{
    resize: both;
}
```

Syntax

```
resize: none
resize: both
resize: horizontal
resize: vertical

resize: inherit
```

and

```
$('.modalHost').draggable();
```

or user the [Native HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)